# how to transmit styles from one element to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

How can I take style for one element and put it into another? My goal is to get rid of the wrapper and .ui-resizable-handlers and leave only img, but with replaced styles form the wrapper.
Is it possible?

```
<div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width:  492px; height: 411px; top: 105px; left: 409px; margin: 0px;">

    <img id="link1" style="position: static; margin: 0px; resize: none; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 411px; width: 492px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/gKY7j0l.jpg" class="ui-resizable">

    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;">
    </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;">
    </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;">
    </div>
</div>
```

so as in this example the outcome will be the img with the styles from the wrapper:

```
<img id="link1" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width:  492px; height: 411px; top: 105px; left: 409px; margin: 0px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/gKY7j0l.jpg" class="ui-resizable">
```

Comment: Have you tried something for yourself, yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to JQuery with few months of experience only.
However, I think this should work.

```
var hold = $('div.ui-wrapper.ui-draggable').attr('style');
$('#link1').attr('style',hold);
```

Then you can remove the wrapper or do whatever you have to do.
To unwrap from wrapper the   http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/   should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should put style into class. Forexample:

```
<div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width:  492px; height: 411px; top: 105px; left: 409px; margin: 0px;">

<img id="link1" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width:  492px; height: 411px; top: 105px; left: 409px; margin: 0px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/gKY7j0l.jpg" class="ui-resizable">
```

to

```
<div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable WRAP">
<img id="link1" class="ui-resizable WRAPIMG">
```

then you can use sth like that:

```
$('#link1').unwrap().removeClass('WRAPIMG').addClass('WRAP');
```